# Get output collection analog

Tags: c#, python

There is python code like:

```
patterns = [s for s in"""
ATGCG
GCATG
CATGC
AGGCA
GGCAT
""".split() if s]

for i1, p1 in enumerate(patterns):
    for i2, p2 in enumerate(patterns):
        if p1[1:] == p2[:len(p2) - 1] and i1 != i2:
            print (p1 + ' -> ' + p2)
```

and output:

```
 AGGCA -> GGCAT
 CATGC -> ATGCG
 GCATG -> CATGC
 GGCAT -> GCATG
```

I want to translate it to c# however I am stuck on for loops and specially on 
if p1[1:] == p2[:len(p2) - 1] and i1 != i2, to emule enumerate(patterns) there is a function

```
public static void Each<T>( this IEnumerable<T> ie, Action<T, int> action )
{
    var i = 0;
    foreach ( var e in ie ) action( e, i++ );
}


patterns = "ATGCG\nGCATG\nCATGC\nAGGCA\nGGCAT";
var elems = patterns.Split(new[] { "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
var strings = new List<string>();
strings.Each( ( elems , n ) =>
{

} );
```

How to complete code?

Comment: `p2[:len(p2) - 1]` can be shortened to `p2[:-1]`.

Comment: One more suggestion, checking `i1 != i2` first will short circuit if they both are the same and you dont have to create two new lists and compare.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LINQ solution, using `SelectMany` to get pairs of items and `Skip`/`Take`/`SequenceEqual` to compare `string` parts:

```
var results = elems.SelectMany((p1, i1) => elems.Where((p2, i2) => i1 != i2).Select(p2 => new { p1, p2 }))
                   .Where(x => x.p1.Skip(1).SequenceEqual(x.p2.Take(x.p2.Length - 1)))
                   .ToList();
```

`results` will be a list of anonymous type objects, with two string properties: `p1` and `p2`. You can easily iterate over the `results` using standard `foreach` loop:

```
foreach(var pair in results)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} -> {1}", pair.p1, pair.p2);
}
```

Prints exactly the same thing your python code does.

You can achieve the same without `Skip`/`Take`/`SequenceEqual`, using `string.Substring` and standard `string` equality check. Replace `Where` part of the solution with following:

```
.Where(x => x.p1.Substring(1) == x.p2.Substring(0, x.p2.Length - 1))
```